# Google MAPS not respecting DIV CSS style

Tags: javascript, css

So I have a div named dgmap to which I am placing my google map. 
The problem I am encountering is the fact that when I show the map, it goes beyond the size I specify in the CSS. FYI I am targeting an HTC evo where the device width is 480px. 
so the width should be 44px. ?? any ideas ?

```
#dgmap {
float:none;
width: 98%;
height: 300px;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) 
{
#dgmap{
float: none;
width: 44px;
height: 250px;      

}
}
```

Comment: 44px sounds too small for a Google map, it could be that it's too little. What code are you using to initialize the map? Are you sure the rule is applied to the browser?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried including the `!important` tag to the width like so:

```
width: 44px !important;
```

Answer (score 0):

Google Maps provides a code with an iframe like:

```
<iframe width="250" height="250" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="https://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&amp;source=s_q&amp;hl=en&amp;geocode=FRCUIAIduoZTCCnnVy7whxtdYDGJG1cii2EBLg%3BFYBHIQIdCrpTCCkfVrpup5IYYDF4sncnN-BKPQ&amp;q=tokyo+to+toshima+ku+ikebukuro+3-30-15.&amp;aq=&amp;sll=37.0625,-95.677068&amp;sspn=34.122306,86.572266&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;t=m&amp;start=0&amp;ll=35.724496,139.70541&amp;spn=0.041808,0.051498&amp;z=13&amp;output=embed"></iframe><br /><small><a href="https://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&amp;source=embed&amp;hl=en&amp;geocode=FRCUIAIduoZTCCnnVy7whxtdYDGJG1cii2EBLg%3BFYBHIQIdCrpTCCkfVrpup5IYYDF4sncnN-BKPQ&amp;q=tokyo+to+toshima+ku+ikebukuro+3-30-15.&amp;aq=&amp;sll=37.0625,-95.677068&amp;sspn=34.122306,86.572266&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;t=m&amp;start=0&amp;ll=35.724496,139.70541&amp;spn=0.041808,0.051498&amp;z=13" style="color:#015492;text-align:left; font-size:10px; font-weight:bold; float:right;">VIEW LARGER MAP</a></small>
```

You have to specify the size of the map inside the iframe.

Answer (score 0):

Hide the the div until necessary then show it calling google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize')

Hope this helps!